# Translation: ところを, ようとする, 側

Tags: grammar, translation, syntax

睡眠薬を飲ませ眠った**ところを**、カツラと服で姿を変え、親子連れを装い密かに遊園地を**抜け出そうとしていた**のだ。

Context: a child was abducted, they made him take a sleeping pill, they changed his hair and clothes in order to disguise him. Eventually the parents　and the park staff managed to save the child.

1. ところを: my main issue with this sentence. What does it mean?
2. 抜け出そうとしていた: could it be here "[they] were about to sneak away"?

ディズニーランド**側**は「最近よく起きている」と説明した。

Also, I noticed in many text this use of 側. Does it mean here something like "the people of Disneyland", namely the staff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. and then
2. Yes

"ディズニーランド側" means Disneyland as a corporation body. It does not identify the person.